# Where goes eth cost in private chain

Tags: private-blockchain, testing, ganache

I have a private test blockchain with ganache. I deploy one contract and make a couple transactions. Looking at the ganache UI I realized that the first account haves a ether consume to make the deploy etc.

In a private chain who/where goes the ether reward?? And if one especific account make lots of transaction the while go down. If that account have 0 ether, that account is disabled???

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> In a private chain who/where goes the ether reward??

Ganache is a local test environment. I don't think it's helpful to think of it as a "private chain", which implies a networked system with all the usual parts of blockchain platform.

There are no block rewards because block mining is only simulated; there are no actual miners.

> If that account have 0 ether, that account is disabled???

If the account has an empty balance, it won't be able to submit test transactions, correct. You have a few options:

- Restart Ganache to reset the balances;
- Transfer funds from one of the other accounts to account 0;
- Pre-fund the accounts with a greater amount of ETH using the relevant field in the "Accounts and Keys" settings.

Comment: Thx for the answer ;D